# A is totally bounded in $l_1 $ if and only if $ (e_n ) \in l_1 .$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(e_n)$ be a sequence of positive real number.
Show that A ={$ x=(x_n) \in l_1: |x_n| \le e_n (n \in N ) $ is totally  bounded in $l_1  $ if and only if $ (e_n ) \in l_1 .$

I have seen similar problem when $|x_n| \le 1/2^n (n \in N ) $ how can I connect this unknown fact to my current problem. hints are always welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

If $(e_n)_n \notin \ell^1$, show that $A $ is not even bounded in $\ell^1$ and thus not totally bounded.

For the other direction, show that $A $ is compact by showing that it is sequentially compact. Indeed, for a sequence  $(x_n^{(m)})_n \in A $, use the usual diagonal argument to construct a subsequence $(x_n^{(m_k)})_n $ such that the limit $x_n =\lim_k x_n^{(m_k)} $ exists for every $n $. Now,  use the dominated convergence theorem to conclude that $(x_n)_n \in A $ is the $\ell^1$ limit of the subsequence $(x_n^{(m_k)})_n $.

Comment: could you please write down in details @ PhoemueX